# Jenkins can not send email using PowerShell script with outlook

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I have a PowerShell script file which sends some specific emails to predetermined users, it uses Outlook and waits Outlook is to be running on the same machine(On Windows platform).

In Jenkins I have tried sending this email with using this powershell script file and a batch file (my PowerShell file embedded within) without success.

At first I was encountering the error `The remote procedure call failed`, but now somehow it is gone and it just does not sending e-mail however; using cmd or PowerShell terminal it works flawlessly.
My code like:

```
# Filters and zips the files before sending by email
Function PreProcessAttachments
{
[cmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$integrationOutputFilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$updateLogFilePath)

$attachments = @()
if (Test-Path $integrationOutputFilePath)
{
    $attachments += $integrationOutputFilePath
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose ("Attachment file $integrationOutputFilePath " + 
        "does not exist. Ignoring..");
}

if (Test-Path $updateLogFilePath)
{
    $attachments += $updateLogFilePath
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose ("Attachment file $integrationOutputFilePath " + 
        "does not exist. Ignoring..");
}

return $attachments
}

Function ReportError
{
[cmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$stream,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$integrationOutputFilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$updateLogFilePath)


$attachments = PreProcessAttachments $integrationOutputFilePath
                    $updateLogFilePath;

$subject = "[Integration Internal Error] at $stream"

$body = "An internal error has occurred during integration.`n";
$body += "`nIntegration Log is attached to this e-mail.`n"

$recipients = "tolga@mycompany.com"

write-output "Sending integration internal error email to: $recipients"
try
{
    SendEmailUsingOutLook $subject $recipients $body $attachments | Out-Null                                
} 
catch
{
    Write-Warning "Couldn't send integration internal error emails $_"
}
}

# send e-mail using OutLook
# note: Attachments should be an array:
Function SendEmailUsingOutLook
{
[cmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$subject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$to,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$body,
    $attachments) 

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application   
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $to
$Mail.Subject = $subject
$Mail.Body = $body

if ($attachments)
{
    foreach ($file in $attachments)
    {
        $Mail.Attachments.Add($file)    
    }
}

$Mail.Send()
}

Function StartPocess
{
$confFile = "path\to\myconf.xml"
LoadConfs $confFile

ReportError -stream $stream
        -integrationOutputFilePath $integrationOutputFilePath
        -updateLogFilePath $updateLogFilePath
}

# Start the script:
StartPocess;
```

Comment: How is your implementation? What's your script? How do you run it? Show some code, so we have something to talk about.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I thought problem is not the code, it is something about permissions of jenkins or windows. Whatever added the code anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that my Jenkins was running as a service (despite it was using using my credentials) and services have problems with comobjects in powershell I think.

1. I stopped the Jenkins from command line usig `jenkins.exe stop`
2. Started it using `{JENKINS_HOME}\jre\bin\java -jar jenkins.war`

This also showed me an empty Jenkins interface but i have copied my old jobs and plugins directory to new installation folder which is under `{USERNAME}\.jenkins` and restarted in the sameway. The service is not running and Jenkins is working from commandline.